# interaction between mhchem \ce command and square brackets

Tags: mhchem

So I have a number of equations with concentrations in them... and using `mhchem` I find an anomaly (probably in my understanding!) when I use `\ce` with `[]`

`\ce{[OH-]}` does not give me  `[OH^{-}]`, but gives me `[OH-]`,  but `\ce{[H+]}` does give me `[H^{+}]`. `[\ce{OH-}]` does give `[OH^{-}]`.

I am not sure what I don't understand here...

with thanks for the help

Chris

Answer (score 3):

Here is my guess: `[` and `]` are part of the compound as far as `mhchem` is concerned and in the middle of a compound a `-` is interpreted as a *single bond* which is what you're seeing in `\ce{[OH-]}`. At the end of a compound a `-` is interpreted as a *negative charge* which is what you're seeing in `\ce{OH-}`. Since `+` does not have a different meaning in the middle of a compound it doesn't behave differently but is interpreted as a positive charge both times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{[OH-]} vs \ce{OH-}

\ce{[OH\bond{-}]}

\ce{[H+]} vs \ce{H+}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The way out is clear: `\ce{[OH^-]}`